# Playing Sound File while Game is Paused in SpriteKit / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

In my game I made a pause menu which pauses the entire game and loads a play button, score label, and a main menu button. When I click the play button, pause button, or main menu button, I want to have it play a sound file. However, it is not letting me do this because everything is paused. I tried manually pausing all nodes, but this is not working. Is there anyway to unpause actions? Also, can you programmatically change a sound file's volume? Below is my code for when the user taps the pause button. I am using xCode 6.4 by the way.

```
if targetNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Pause {
        switch gameState {
        case (.GameRunning):
            if paused == false {
                runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("beep1.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
                paused = true
        pauseScene()
            }
        case (.GameOver):
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the sound is not running because paused is true, so the if statement returns false and the sound is not played. Try playing the sound as soon as the button is tapped without the if statement. That way, the sound is played independent of it.

Comment: Instead of pausing the scene,  create a node that houses all your game elements,, then pause this node.  This way you can run sound on the scene